# Clock / Weather widget does not display on the home screen

Tags: app-widgets

I accidentally deleted my clock/weather from my home screen on my Samsung Galaxy S3. I downloaded a new app but when I add it to my home screen it just stays small, when I tap on it it just gives me "important information" on how to add it. It is added, it just won't open! Help!

Comment: What app is it and are you using the stock Home/Launcher? If not, what Home/Launcher are you using?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you've added an app shortcut instead of a widget. As geffchang says, be sure to click **Widgets**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the app drawer. At the top, you should see `Apps` and `Widgets`.
2. Click `Widgets`, and scroll through the pages. Look for the weather widget.
3. Once you find the widget, long-press on it and drag it to your home screen.

**EDIT #1:** Here's an example. In this case, I am using the Accuweather app. AND, I'm not using the default launcher, but you should find something similar.

[image]

Comment: I did that but, it just stays the small little icon, and does not actually display the time or weather...

Comment: @Michele See the screenshot I added. Look at the red boxes. That's what you should be looking for.